# Which of Context and Alias is more useful?

Tags: crystal-reports, alias, business-intelligence, business-objects

During tables linking we will have loops which will result in duplicate records in report, so to overcome we use `Context` and `Alias`.

To the extent I know both serve the same purpose but what is the difference between the two and which one is more effective.

One thing I am aware is alias creates more tables but all tables are of logical structure so is alias more useful that context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is kind of like asking, what's the more useful tool: a wrench or a screwdriver?  It depends on the task at hand.

You are correct that aliases create additional logical tables.  Sometimes that's the desired approach, but not always.

One way I approach the question is to first determine whether there are multiple logical dimensions for a single physical dimension.

For example, consider a fact table with two date keys: `transaction_dt_key`, `completed_dt_key`.  Both of these are associated with a `date_key` field in a `date_dim` table.  You would, of course, create a loop if you were to join both fact fields to the date dim table.  In this case, an alias is appropriate -- you would alias the dim table, join the fact keys to the original and alias table, then create a new object associated with the alias table.

Another way to look at this example is that the Transaction Date and Completed Date are *two different things*.  Therefore, it is appropriate to have them represented by two different objects, and it follows that this would be accomplished by an alias.

In this respect, the design in the universe will more closely match the **logical** design of the data mart rather than its **physical** design.

Contexts, on the other hand, are useful when the same dimension table is associated with multiple fact tables.

Consider this example: the model has
`customer_dim`
`store_dim`
`sales_fact`
`returns_fact`

Both fact tables have a `customer_id` and `store_id` field.  Joining all keys would create a loop.  In this case, a context would be appropriate -- one context to include `sales_fact` and the two dims, and the other context to include `returns_fact` and the two dims.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and apologize for late reply bit busy in office stuff... but one confusion still exists in my mind is since alias is a logical structure will it implact any performance and which one is better performance with context or performance with alias.

Comment: Contexts and aliases perform very different functions, so it's not easy to compare them in terms of performance.  With that said, an alias is nothing more than a re-naming of a table, so there would be no performance impact from using one.

Comment: Thanks for your continous help.... I understood one thing here is both context and alias are the different way of forming a query... am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

They both serve a general purpose of controlling loops in a universe.
Personally, I've used them both in the same universe. They can be complementary.
I totally agree with Joe's explanation and examples.
Since Aliases can be physically seen on the model, the maintenance can be less challenging than Contexts.